# Priority queue for Common Lisp?

Tags: data-structures, lisp, common-lisp, priority-queue

I've been looking everywhere for a priority queue implementation for Common Lisp that works, and so far, I've not had much luck. As I'm fairly new to Common Lisp, whenever I see a huge warning/error dump from the REPL, I'm not really sure what to do about it. This isn't helped by the fact that all the priority queue implementations I've found seem to be really old.

Could someone suggest one to me?

Comment: Please note that "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: If you have a particular question about a particular priority queue implementation, though, that could be on topic.  Seeing a "huge warning/error dump from the REPL" isn't information for anyone to help with it though;  you'll need to provide more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick search for "queue" on http://quickdocs.org turned up a few choices.  I looked at the description and API of `priority-queue` and it seems sensible.  You can get it from [Quicklisp](http://quicklisp.org).